# using CSS to reorganize DIVs

Tags: css

I'm trying to modify an SMF theme
DIV1 and DIV2 are organized in the html so that div1 comes first and is displayed above div2. 
I want to switch their places using css, is this possible? and how can I accomplish it?

Comment: It would better if you try this using JS, rather than just CSS

Comment: i only have access to the .css

Answer (score 1):

With the sliver of information you've given:

> DIV1 and DIV2 are organized in the
>   html so that div1 comes first and is
>   displayed above div2

I'm assuming you have a structure [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/BY7v9/):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

You can do this using `absolute` inside `relative` positioning.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/BY7v9/1/

You can get a more specific answer if you provide.. more specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a 100% height `margin` to the top `<div>` and a -100% `margin` to the bottom one. That might get them to swap places. It could have other unintended consequenses, though. You might need to fiddle with additional styles also, such as `overflow`, as well to get it working.

Using `position:relative;` might work too. You could then specify `top` for the two divs to move one up and the other down. Again, this will affect the rest of the layout. If that doesn't work, `position:relative;` for one of them and `position:absolute` for the other might work better.

Depending on the layout, using `float` might do the trick. But that definitely has some interesting quirks if your layout isn't already set up for floated elements.

Worst case, you could use `position:absolute;` and define a fixed position for everything.

The main trouble you'll have with almost all these options will be keeping the container element the right size. If you can fix the size of that (or if it's already fixed) then your job will be a lot easier.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`float:right` on the left one and `float:left` on the right one.
It *could* work, but I couldn't possibly know from the little you've said.

You might also need to put this psuedoclass to one of the divs:

```
:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```